# Flutter - Adapt size of container to content in it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container with a stack as child but when the text has too many lines it gets cut off. I would like the container to adapt to the text.

[this is how it looks so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcwYE.jpg)

Comment: Please add some code so we can help.

Comment: Are you having fix width for container, and add some code so we can help you